# Stand-alone SQL query for dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server

I need to build a stand-alone SQL which will use data from sample table (only one table) below.

Below example is for a single ID. In below example, we can see that the ID has 5 stage values, so the output should display these 5 stage values and the number of days for these processed stages. It is possible for ID records to have +/- 5 stages.  Depending on the number of stages, corresponding columns (Stage) should be dynamically generated with the no. of days column (Time) value.

Sample Table Data:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------|
ID   |  PRE_VAL       |  NEXT_VAL     |  CHANGE_DATE |  REPORT_DATE   | 
-----|----------------|---------------|--------------|----------------|
11   |  NEW           |  READY PULL   |  02-JAN-18   |    01-JAN-18   |
11   |  READY PULL    |  READY SPLICE |  04-JAN-18   |    01-JAN-18   |
11   |  READY SPLICE  |  READY TEST   |  07-JAN-18   |    01-JAN-18   |
11   |  READY TEST    |  COMPLETE     |  11-JAN-18   |    01-JAN-18   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Expected SQL Output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   |  Stage |  Time   |  Stage      | Time    |  Stage       | Time     ......
-----|--------|---------|-------------|---------|--------------|--------     
11   |  NEW   |  1 Day  |  READY PULL | 2 Days  | READY SPLICE | 3 Days
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have tagged this question for both `sql-server` and `oracle`. Which database are you  really using? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to query first the columns that there will be, and then construct a dynamic SQL based on those. What have you tried so far / where is the problem?

Comment: retained sql-server tag now.

Comment: I am facing 2 challenges as of now:
1) Using only a stand-alone sql, how can we have dynamic columns 
  depending of number of stages for a specific set of records?
2) Transpose in SQL? LISTAGGR?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stand-alone sql"?

Comment: stand-alone means a "single, independent SQL statement".

Comment: Does an anonymous block count as a "single, independent SQL statement"?

Comment: No, anonymous block doesn't count as a stand-alone SQL.

Using a single SELECT sql clause, I need to solve this.

Comment: You can't create + run dynamic SQL in a single statement, unless stored procedures, user defined functions, running several exec statements inside a single exec or something like that is considered as single statement.

Comment: You should really describe your restriction better, and especially where this restriction is coming from. Maybe you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: This needs to be developed as part of a report, whose output can only be extracted from a single SQL statement. If (James Z) you are not able to do it, its fine, I am still trying from my end. Trying different approaches eg. bind variables